# Extjs , how to render a button to template

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-mvc

i'm new with Extjs and was wonder if there is an option to render a button inside a div in  the template. I'm adding the files:

```
Ext.define('itfm.application.view.SystemStatusHeader', {

extend: 'Ext.panel.Header',
alias: 'widget.systemStatusHeader',
headingTpl: '<div><span id="{id}-textEl" class="{cls}-text {cls}-text-{ui}">{title}</span><span id="targetId"></span></div>',
subTitleTpl: '<div id="{id}-textEl" class="{cls}-text {cls}-text-{ui} {cls}-subtitle">{subtitle}</div>',


initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    if(me.subtitle)  {
        var tpl = new Ext.Template(me.subTitleTpl);
        me.headingTpl = me.headingTpl.concat(tpl.apply({subtitle: me.subtitle,cls:'{cls}'}));
    }

    this.callParent(arguments);

      if(me.btn){
          renderTo:'#targetId';  --> how can i set it inside the div
      }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?114317-Button-In-a-Template&p=534588&viewfull=1#post534588

There is a simple example code aswell.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: He asked, I told him where is the solution. Pretty simple. End of story.

Comment: Yes, it's there but you really have to dig for it. A simple summary would be great. Without an explanation, this should be a comment